# What can I say about compatibility between predictions and results?

Tags: measurements, statistics, error-analysis

If I have these theoretical predictions:
\begin{align}
\omega_{p_1} = 4.5132 \pm 0.0003~\text{rad/s} && \omega_{p_2} = 4.5145 \pm 0.0002~\text{rad/s}\\
\omega_{b_1} = 0.0707 \pm 0.0003~\text{rad/s} && \omega_{b_2} = 0.0700 \pm 0.0002~\text{rad/s}
\end{align}

And I got these experimental results:
\begin{align}
\omega_{p_1} = 4.5148 \pm 0.0001~\text{rad/s} && \omega_{p_2} = 4.5147 \pm 0.0001~\text{rad/s}\\
\omega_{b_1}  = 0.0702 \pm 0.0001~\text{rad/s} && \omega_{b_2} = 0.0707 \pm 0.0001~\text{rad/s}
\end{align}

Can I only say that the experimental measurements are incompatible with the theoretical predictions even if the discrepancy is in the order of $\sim 10^{-3}\text{ s}$? Or can I say something else more?

Comment: Might [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) be better suited for this question?

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't think so. Perhaps it would also be on topic on CV, but this strikes me as a physics question.

Comment: If your uncertainty estimates are good (on both theory and experiment) than the error is 2.5--4 times the uncertainty. The small size of the error makes this a precise measurement but does not change the basic fact that you are several sigma out in three of four channels.

Comment: Thanks @dmckee. If I have underestimated the uncertainties, and they're 1-2.5 sigma out, instead, may I say that they're statistical fluctuations?